# where should I download latest GDAL binaries and tools to code in c#

Tags: c#, gdal

I want to access geopatial raster data and perform certain manipulations using GDAL in a C# project. Could some one let me know where should I download the latest binaries (that includes utilities, csharp dlls & sample data if any) for the latest version of GDAL library. Preferable greater than GDAL 1.7.0 as I will be using gdaldem.

Any other inputs are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: http://vbkto.dyndns.org:1280/sdk/

You can use this aswell: http://gdal2tilescsharp.codeplex.com/

But I prefer the first one. Works fine to me:)

Comment: It was the original hosting. Author moved his resources. Link was up to date in 2012...

Answer (score 0):

You can download using link.
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Also if you want to compile, you can use this link. https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrCsharpCompile

This link describes the primary steps when creating the GDAL/OGR C# binaries from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can find compiled binaries at http://www.gisinternals.com/

Just add reference to \bin\gdal\csharp*_csharp.dll, add *_wrap.dll to your output location and other gdal dlls.

Answer (score 0):

This is the newest one which uses .Net Core.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gdal.Core/